# Mediation question – what if path c' is greater than path c but process indicates that M variable is mediator

Tags: regression, spss, mediation

In classic mediation model, process gave the following results:

x variable predicts y – path c

F(1,510)=21.38; p<.001, R2=.05;
   **b=.19**, t(510)=4.62, p<.001

x variable predicts M – path a

F(1,510)=7.70, p<.05, R2=.02;
   b=0.11, t(510)=2.77, p<.05

x and M together predicting y

F(2,509)=31.14, p<.001, R2=.13;
   M variable predicts y – path b

```
b=-.31, t(509)=-6.24, p<.001
```

x variable is not supposed to predict y or supposed to be lessened predicting y – path c'

```
 **b=.23,** t(509)=5.63, p<.001
```

Sobel test (normal theory test) = z score test if c-c'=/0
   Z=-2.51, p=.0121, se=.0135, effect=-.0340

How can I explain why is path c' greater than path c? Is variable M really a mediator?
(M is not suppressor variable. It doesn't meet necessary conditions for suppressor variable

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: If your direct effect is larger than the total (direct+indirect) effect, then it means you have a negative mediation effect. Of course this only holds in case your model is correct (so there no confounders in your regressions - or there are and you are controlling for them, and they are not affected by $x$).